# embedding geojson.io with iframe

Tags: html, iframe

i am using django and i have a method that generates a URL for a certain map on geojson.io
Now i am trying to implement this into my html code. When using a button that opens a new tab with the url everything works fine, but now i want to embed this onto my page instead of opening a new tab when clicking a button. So for this i read about "iframe". Now the problem is when passing my URL to src into "iframe" it doesnt display the map into the frame but rather opens the URL as if one would type the URL into the browser.

I tried it using an absolut path and using a variable, both had the same result as mentioned above.

Is this a problem with geojson.io or am i doing something wrong with my code?
The URL is encoded with encodeURIComponent doing it in django with the urllib package.

Here is my html code i implemented with the absolut path of the generated URL.

```
<iframe  id="Example"
        title="Example"
        width="300"
        height="200"
        src="http://geojson.io/#data=data:application/json,%7B%22features%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22geometry%22%3A%20%7B%22coordinates%22%3A%20%5B8.6792%2C%2050.1171%5D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Point%22%7D%2C%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Feature%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22geometry%22%3A%20%7B%22coordinates%22%3A%20%5B11.5727%2C%2048.1404%5D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Point%22%7D%2C%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Feature%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22geometry%22%3A%20%7B%22coordinates%22%3A%20%5B%5B8.6792%2C%2050.1171%5D%2C%20%5B11.5727%2C%2048.1404%5D%5D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22LineString%22%7D%2C%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Feature%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22FeatureCollection%22%7D">
</iframe>
```

So my question is, how do i embed a generated geojson.io URL with "iframe" (or others) and why is it linking to the site instead of displaying it in the frame?